# When create database in SQL Server 2016 log file size is huge

Tags: database, sql-server-2016

Below query used to create database in SQL Server 2016

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB_v821 ON ( Name = 'TestDB_v821', FILENAME = 'E:\Data\TestDB_v821.mdf', FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    LOG ON ( NAME = 'TestDB_v821_Log', FILENAME = 'E:\Log\TestDB_v821_Log.ldf', FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

The query taking more time than normal. When i check the log file size using `select * from sys.dm_db_log_space_usage`

```
database_id total_log_size_in_bytes used_log_space_in_bytes used_log_space_in_percent log_space_in_bytes_since_last_backup
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------------------
17          2508193792              8749568                 0.3488394                 225280
```

Need to know why the simple create database statement creates the hug log file. It is same behavior when try to create other database also. Is it due to some setting. Please help me on this.

Comment: Why not define a starting size? Out of interest, what is the size of the log file for your `model` database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take the initial size and auto-growth settings from the [`model` database](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-transaction-log-administration-best-practices/), so you need to reduce it there if you want smaller defaults.

Comment: This does seem to be contrary to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but I've just tested setting the model log file to 1123 MB and verified a `CREATE DATABASE X` used that size